# Survey Database Design. Too Many Bridge Tables?

Tags: database-design, ms-access-2010

First things first:

- This is a database for storing surveys and their responses so that they can then be analyzed using reporting software
- It is modeled in MS Access 2010 but will be migrated to a more robust platform (like MS SQL Server) once the design is finalized
- This is only part of the database, the part I would like help with

Questions:

- I'm worried about the amount of bridge tables I have (**Survey Sections**, **Section Questions**, etc.) and how it might be overcomplicated. Can you see any way I can reduce the complication but maintain speed and efficiency?
- I foresee that the **Answers** table will potentially have thousands of rows (If there are a thousand respondents taking a survey with 60 questions). I am wondering if this would be a problem, and are there other ways to store the answers?
- Generally, does anyone see a potential issue with this design? (This is the most complex database I have ever created)

[image: ERD]

Comment: 60,000 rows is not a lot, rest easy with that one.

Comment: Can a user do multiple surveys?  Do your answers also need to key off survery id as well as answer id?

Comment: 60,000 per survey, with the potential to have hundreds of surveys

Comment: Also, the user_id is an arbitrary number to preserve the anonymity of the user. So, simply, no a user cannot do multiple surveys

Answer (score 1):

You can clean things up by designing the system such that a Question can only exist on one Section, and a Section can only exist on one Survey. The same applies to QuestionOptions, though this area is less clear to me. This will eliminate the need for those intersection tables. This change may require you to add code in your client application to *copy* or *move* a section or question (including all Options) from one Survey/Section to another.

You need to add a column to Section, Questions, and OptionGroups to store positional/ordinal information, because you will want them to be presented in a pre-selected order.

Also, you have some small tables that consist almost entirely of foreign keys. In those cases, it's not always a good idea to use an autonumber ID column as a surrogate key, but instead define a primary key that is a composite key of your foreign keys. This is especially true if you opt to keep all those intersection tables. If you don't do this, you need to at least also have a unique constraint on those columns.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Also, great idea with the positional information column. Totally overlooked that.